# update value from for loop running in Thread To Client side lable

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one long running Thread.In this Thread having for loop this will Iterate 40000 times. For every 100 iteration i need to send 100 value to client side. That should be in c#

Comment: Are you using Ajax or an UpdatePanel? 
Is the an asp.net page, handler, or service?
How are you launching the thread?

Comment: i am using ajax,on click i am running the thread